# Cookies accessible from domain.com and www.domain.com

Tags: php, cookies

If I create a cookie using PHP as:

```
setcookie('pctlang',$setlocale,time()+3600*24*365,'/');
```

From domain.com, my users can access my site using also www.domain.com, but in that url the cookies created in domain.com are not accessible.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
setcookie('pctlang',$setlocale,time()+3600*24*365,'/',".domain.com");
```